# cron jobs were running, then not at some point

Tags: cron, magento2.3.2

It doesn't seem like the cron job is doing anything.  I keep getting warnings in the admin panel that the indexes are invalid.  The crontab file is as expected.  The emails are not getting sent either.

```
#~ MAGENTO START 
* * * * * /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/steamspeed.com/httpdocs/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/vhosts/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php /var/www/update/cron.php >> /var/www/httpdocs/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php /var/www/httpdocs/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/httpdocs/var/log/setup.cron.log
* * * * * /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php /var/www/httpdocs/bin/magento php indexer:reindex
#~ MAGENTO END 
* * * * * date >> ~/cron-test.txt
```

So, I added that cron-text.txt job, and it adds the date/time to that txt file.

```
~$ cat cron-test.txt
Tue Dec 24 01:30:01 UTC 2019
```

Currently, my crown config is set to defaults.  Any suggestion why nothing seems to be happening?

[image: default cron settings]

Answer (score 1):

May Issue on cron setup so let run the below command

**//cron setup**

```
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento cron:install
```

**//cron run**

```
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento cron:run
```

Also, check-in the log file may be permission issue more reference check [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)